# Controlar datos con argv en python

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo la siguiente duda.

Quiero poder controlar el ingreso de datos en caso de que exista un valor que no se ingrese.

En este caso quiero controlar si es que utilidad_AA no se ingrese, te muestre un mensaje.

```
import sys

precio              = int(sys.argv[1])
usuarios            = int(sys.argv[2])
gastos              = int(sys.argv[3])
utilidad_AA         = int(sys.argv[4])

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print('Te falta el ultimo campo')
else:
    print('Muchas gracias, datos guardados')
```

Me da un indexError y no entiendo que podría estar mal. Me imagino que es super simple, pero estoy recién aprendiendo.

Saludos y muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Necesita verificar la longitud de la lista antes de obtener valores de ella

Comment: Ahí es donde estoy con dudas, estoy usando un if len, pero no sé si debo verificar la lista entera o el espacio en donde se almacena el ultimo valor.
Y no sé la sintaxis correcta para verificarlo, pero podrías echar una manito por favor.

Comment: Si lo hace de manera simple, debe verificar que la longitud de la lista sea 4 y mostrar qué campos se deben completar. Es aproximadamente lo que hiciste, pero debes reorganizar la recepción de datos de `argv` debajo del cheque. Si necesita algo más complicado, es mejor usar módulos como [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) o [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algunas cosas mal:

- La comprobación `if len(sys.argv) != 3` la haces "demasiado tarde". Antes de llegar a ella están tus intentos de acceder a `sys.argv[1]`, etc... cualquiera de los cuales fallará si el elemento correspondiente no existe. Verificar la longitud de esa lista debe ser lo primero que hagas.
- La comprobación `if len(sys.argv) != 3` no parece apropiada de todas formas ¿por qué distinto de 3? Parece que tu programa espera 4 parámetros y no 3. Por otro lado `sys.argv[0]` no es un parámetro sino el propio nombre del script, de modo que al final, cuando el usuario especifica todos los parámetros esperados, `len(sys.argv)` será 5. Por tanto la comparación debería ser con 5 y no con 3.
- Tampoco parece apropiado el mensaje de error. Si el `len(sys.argv)` no es 5, es posible que sea 4 (en cuyo caso el usuario no introdujo el último parámetro, como indicas en el error), pero también es posible que sea 3, 2... es decir el usuario pudo olvidar varios parámetros. Incluso puede ser 6, que indicaría que ha introducido parámetros de más (esto no sería problema a la hora de acceder a los que te interesan, pero podrías querer informarle de ello de todas formas).

Por tanto una forma más correcta sería:

```
num_params = len(sys.argv) - 1
if num_params < 4:
   print("No has introducido suficientes parámetros. Faltan", 4-num_params)
   quit()
elif num_params > 4:
   print("ADVERTENCIA: Has introducido", num_params-4, "parámetros de más. Los ignoraré")

precio              = int(sys.argv[1])
usuarios            = int(sys.argv[2])
gastos              = int(sys.argv[3])
utilidad_AA         = int(sys.argv[4])
```

Un último truco "avanzado". La asignación final puedes hacerla en una sola línea aprovechando el desempaquetado de iterables que tiene python, y la función `map()` que permite aplicar otra función a cada elemento de un iterable

```
precio, usuarios, gastos, utilidad_AA = map(int, sys.argv[1:5])
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! me ayudaron bastante tus consejos.
El != 3 lo puse porque estaba probando con algunos condicionales, había intentado == 4, etc. 
Pero con lo que me explicaste me lo dejaste super claro.

Comment: Intente usar tu ejemplo para un ejercicio que me plantearon, pero no pude, no es necesario que me des la respuesta pero si me puedes dar una pista te lo agradecería mucho.

"Crear el programa emprendedor3.py donde el usuario ingrese el precio, el número de usuarios, los gastos y las utilidades del año anterior, este último parámetro será optativo. Si el usuario no lo ingresa, se asumirá 1000 dólares como base. El programa debe calcular y mostrar como porcentaje la razón entre las utilidades actuales y las del año anterior."

Comment: Pues en ese caso puedes mirar si num_params < 3 para mostrar un error; si num_params == 3 en cuyo caso los lees de argv [1], [2] y [3] y asignas el que falta a 1000; o si num_params es ==4 en cuyo caso asignas los cuatro. El caso en que te pasen más de 4 puedes dejarlo sin comprobar. Te dejo que pienses la estructura de los condicionales necesaria , pero básicamente son una serie de `if`/`elif`.

Comment: No me resulto :(
Me podrías indicar el resultado, no te lo pediría si no fuese necesario, debo entregarlo hoy y estoy con demasiado trabajo.
Prometo que nunca se me olvidará como hacerlo

Comment: Prácticamente ya te lo había dicho. `if num_params <3: print("No has introducido suficientes parámetros") elif num_params == 3: utilidad_AA=1000 else: utilidad_AA=sys.argv[4]` y después asignas (fuera ya del if) las restantes variables desde `sys.argv[1]`, `[2]` y `[3]`